# Where do I roll over capital losses from a previous year on my tax forms?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, capital-loss

I use TurboTax and a couple of years ago I lost money in the stock market. I haven't made any money in the stock market since then but plan to start investing again and wanted to make sure that the government has my losses logged. I did file them in my 2020 taxes but am unsure how to make sure they roll over into the current year. What form do I need to fill out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've been using TurboTax every year it'll almost certainly import your capital loss carryover from previous years. If not, it should allow you to enter this information. Either way, check on [Schedule D](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sd.pdf) lines 6 and 14 to verify your short- and long-term capital loss carryovers. These lines refer to a worksheet for calculating the carryovers [here](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040sd#en_US_2021_publink24331id0e493).

Comment: How would I input losses post fact. I have losses in 2019 that I never used and did not file in 2020. How do I add those in?

Comment: I don't use TurboTax anymore so it's difficult to say but it should ask you if it doesn't import it automatically. If you didn't file in 2020 presumably it's because your taxable income was 0, and therefore your capital loss carryover would stay intact.

Comment: @GeroldAstor+ i don't think you can skip a year. The 2021 worksheet specifically calls for amounts from your 2020 return, not any earlier one; contrast with 8606 where it tells you how to find and use IRA basis from the most recent applicable return back to 1987. Also at the top of page 1 of the schedule D 2021 instructions it lists purposes including "To report a capital loss carryover from 2020 to 2021" -- specifically "from 2020".

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 That may be true. If so they could just file for 2020 now. Since they didn't owe anything there should be no penalty.